# pose estimation?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am currently working on pose estimation from 2D to 3D point correspondences. 2D points are of the following form:

```
X: 2345.12  Y:1234.45
```

3D points are of the following form:

```
X: 0.22218997762212644 Y: 0.78954199756837817 Z: 4.3359541556384427
```

The focal length and distortion coefficients are :

```
3870.2997285884562 -0.068235490696109416 0.021799724491707737
```

I am looking to use 4-5 such correspondences and estimate the pose. I am using openCV for the desired purpose. Can someone plz help me how to do it via POSIT algorithm and how to calculate the estimation error rate?

Any guidance will be really appreciated . . . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like cv::solvePnP is the function you are looking for...

[OpenCV docs: solvePnP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=solvepnp#bool%20solvePnP%28InputArray%20objectPoints,%20InputArray%20imagePoints,%20InputArray%20cameraMatrix,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs,%20OutputArray%20rvec,%20OutputArray%20tvec,%20bool%20useExtrinsicGuess,%20int%20flags%29)

Below it is solvePnPRansac, as well.

Comment: I am wondering about the camera matrix and coefficient matrix. The camera matrix needs fx,fy,cx,cy. I have only 1 focal length. Can I use it for both fx and fy. Moreover I will use the center of the image for cx and cy. Waiting for guidance plz . .

Comment: I have no idea how accurate those numbers are, but you could certainly try it... cx and cy relate to the center of the focal lens over the CCD inside the camera, and are usually near the center of the image.  It depends on the application, but for most you should try to accurately calibrate it, especially if you hope to get reliable external pose information.  OpenCV has tools for that as well, at the top of the page currently posted.

Comment: Note that, with ordinary digital cameras and a calibration rig that is not manufactured/machined very accurately, it is preferable to force-fix the fx/fy ratio to the one specified by the CCD maufacturer, skew = 0 and (cx, cy) == image center. The Principal Point (cx, cy) is ordinarily very hard to calibrate accurately, since it is intrinsically confused with the component parallel to the image plane of the camera translation. To get it with any accuracy you need several images with good observed camera motion between them.

Comment: @FrancoCallari Excellent point.  For trying to infer pose from a single set of 2D-3D correspondences, the quality of your estimation is sensitive to the quality of the intrinsics and the 3D point distribution.  Given the 3D points, you could filter instead of getting a tight calibration.  This is what RANSAC effectively does.  You could even filter intelligently and do better.  However, the better the intrinsics, the more usable inliers, and thus the tighter the confidence on the pose estimate.